# Authenticate users to azure function when user is authenticated in web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Application running as a web app in Azure App Service. This web app calls an Azure Function via HttpClient from a Controller. Authentication/Authorization is configured in the web app with Azure Active Directory. I need the user to also be authenticated when a call to the Azure Function is made so that I can access the user Claims.
I tried to also configure Authentication in the Azure Function itself but this resulted in an "Unauthorized response" whenever I called the function from my web app.
Is there a way to make both the web app and the Azure function use the same Active Directory Authentication. So that when a user is authenticated to the web app, he does not need to authenticate again in the Azure function and all the User Claims would be available in the function itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three different approaches that would work.

**Using Bearer token.**

Create two separate application registrations, one for the web application and one for the function application. Setup the Authentication/Authorization feature for the respective applications, with both configured to require AAD access. Give the web application's AAD app registration permission to access the function application's AAD app registration.

To make sure that the access token of your web application is a JWT that can be used to contact your function application, you need to add additional login parameters to your web application. To do this, follow the [instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#limit-the-domain-of-sign-in-accounts), but instead set `additionalLoginParams` to `resource=<your-function-app-registration-client-id>`.

When a user makes an authenticated request to the web app, a header should be populated called `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN` which should be an access token with an audience of your Function application's app registration. This can then be used as a bearer token to the Function application API calls, which should satisfy the authentication/authorization requirements of the function application.

**Using on-behalf-of flow**

Create two separate application registrations, one for the web application and one for the function application. Setup the Authentication/Authorization feature for the respective applications, with both configured to require AAD access. Give the web application's AAD app registration permission to access the function application's AAD app registration.

Then, follow the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) so that the web application can get an access token for an authenticated user user for the function application. There are several libraries that help with this flow. See [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) if your app registrations are AAD V1 apps, or [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) if your app registrations are AAD V2 apps.

**Use Client-Directed-Flow (X-ZUMO-AUTH)**

Create two separate application registrations, one for the web application and one for the function application. Setup the Authentication/Authorization feature for the respective applications, with both configured to require AAD access. Give the web application's AAD app registration permission to access the function application's AAD app registration.

To make sure that the access token of your web application can be used to authenticate against your function application, you need to add additional login parameters to your web application. To do this, follow the [instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#limit-the-domain-of-sign-in-accounts), but instead set `additionalLoginParams` to `resource=<your-function-app-registration-client-id>`.

When a user makes an authenticated request to the web app, a header should be populated called `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN` which should be an access token with an audience of your Function application's app registration, along with an id token in the header `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN`. Make a POST request to https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad with the payload
`{"id_token": <id-token>, "access_token": <access-token>}`. This will return a session token, that you can attach as an `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header to authenticate requests.

NOTE: The claims in this option will be the claims of the authentication token, which are not the claims of the identity provider like in the first two options. To get the same claims as the other options, set the application setting `WEBSITE_AUTH_ZUMO_USE_TOKEN_STORE_CLAIMS` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way that I can access the "Claims" of the user directly within the function app given that the application itself sends the authenticated request to the function app?

Comment: I did not manage to do any of the suggestions. Both the options resulted in an "Unauthorized" response. What worked for me was making a post request from the web app to "https://myazurefunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad" passing in the access token (X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN) and getting the authentication token. Than making a corresponding request to the function app and passing the authentication token in the Header x-zumo-auth. With this option however, I cannot get all the claims that I need.

Comment: I have revised my answer, which fixes the Bearer token example, as well as explains how to get the zumo auth token scenario to work.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon just wondering if you still *need* to set up separate app registrations for this scenario, or can you use a single registration?

Comment: @stevenrcfox, technically you can, although the official recommendations would likely be to have one for the client and one for the server, just so you can more cleanly configure the two separately. However, unless you are being a purist, you can probably get away with a single app registration. I personally would draw the distinction based on what your company considers the application boundary, and have one app registration per application.