# Use authentication of App service for authorization of Function App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

In Azure, I have a web application App service which communicates with the Function App. I have Azure AD authentication on the web application. I want to make sure that the function apps are called only by authenticated users.

As an option, I was thinking if it is possible to pass some token or any data from the web application to the function app, to verify the user.

If not, please share any other way to do this.

Note: Web app is in Angular and Function App is in Java.

Comment: You are required to test Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated property to ensure that the user or application invoking the function app is authenticated.

Comment: The Function App is in java. I have updated this info in the question.

if someone has authenticated in the front end, and then I am calling the function app (API) from the frontend, how will the function app know that whether someone has authenticated or not?

To let Function App know about that, what needs to be done?

Comment: There's another thread on SO which solves this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430002/authenticate-users-to-azure-function-when-user-is-authenticated-in-web-app

Answer (score 1):

We could use the access token to access your Azure function API directly if your azure function authentication level is anonymous or function key is also required. The detailed steps are as below.

1. Configure Azure AD for Azure Function. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#auth.
2. Get Access token

```
Method : POST
URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/your directory ID/oauth2/token 

Header:  
        Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body
       "grant_type ": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "the app id of the Azure AD application you project Azure function",
        "client_secret": ":the app secret of the Azure AD application you project Azure function",
        "resource": "the app id of the Azure AD application you project Azure function"
```

[image]

3. Call Azure Function
   [image]